# how to Installing and testing the "gmail contextual gadget"

Tags: iframe, google-apps-marketplace, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets, iframe-app

I wanna ask about how to Installing and testing the "gmail contextual gadget".
https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#installing_and_testing_the_gadget I'm getting trouble the deprecated document. In first step "1. Log into the console."  but when I click it bring me to a page about Apps Marketplace
In this page, the document said, before you publish, you must pay a small fee using google wallet(it's 1st point in "Before you publish"). But when I click the link "Google Wallet", which has link: 
https://checkout.google.com/
it shows 404 error page.
Please help me. Thank you!!!

Comment: The [Google Apps Marketplace](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/) is deprecated, so you can no longer publish on there. It has been replaced with the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/), but I'm not sure if you can publish contextual gadgets there (an add on would be more appropriate). You can find more details on creating a Chrome Web Store developer account [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/about_signup).

Comment: thanks for answering. I'm still really confused now. Especially when I find in configuration of Google Apps Marketplace SDK in google developer console, at the end of the configuration page, there is a option called gmail contextual gadget, I'm trying with this option but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer true. The Google apps marketplace is back in business and is its own marketplace. You need to enable Google apps marketplace sdk api in the project to make it work.